# Is it possible to redesign OpenStreetMap tiles?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, leaflet, mapbox

We have an application working with OpenLayers and are using OpenStreetmap for the map tiles, however they don't look great.

Is there anyway to style these maps?

I read something about Mapbox but it uses Leaflet API, however we use OpenLayers and our app is heavily using it.  What options do I have?

Answer (score 7):

MapBox doesn't require you to use the [MapBox.js](http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/) API - you can use your customized tiles with OpenLayers easily by using [OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/XYZ-js.html).

Comment: I've signed up for a mapbox account, can you give me an overview of what to do to get it working with openlayers? i'm not quite sure

Comment: Create a map in your account, click 'Publish', click 'MapBox.js', copy the map id and then in OpenLayers-land, `OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ('MapBox', 'http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/[mapid]/${z}/${y}/${x}.png')`

Comment: +1 Answers the question. Just wanted to highlight that as @Burton449 notes, MapBox free usage is limited.

Answer (score 6):

You will have to host the openstreet map data on your own server and generate your styled tiles yourself. Look at [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) for tiling. MapBox could be a solution that is hosted in the cloud, but it is not free to use (but you can have limited free use and storage).

Comment: MapBox does have a free option. You can customize tiles, which MapBox will cloud host free for up to 3k map views.  50MB of storage is also included in the [free plan](http://www.mapbox.com/plans/).

Comment: Ok, I did not know that. You mean 3k map hits (refresh, pan, zoom = 1 hit) or 3k "user-session" view?

Comment: I made a custom tileset on their website (as opposed to tilemill), and worked it into a website I'm developing.  With all of the refreshes I did to get the look I wanted (and sharing the page with a few others) I have 522 map views.  There might be a more specific explanation of map views on their site, but I haven't seen it.

Comment: From http://www.mapbox.com/plans/ -- 15 tiles is a 'map view'

Comment: Mapbox would be too expensive with what i'm planning
I do like Cloud made designs, but would like to use these with Mapnik

Is it possible to get good looking maps like with Cloudmade using MapNik?

Comment: You dont need mapnik, you can tile and cache your Cloudmade using tilestache or tilecache with WMS (or named URL) plugin using your Cloudmade WMS URL (probably Cloudmade is using Mapnik under the hood already)

Comment: Thanks, i'm a little overwhelmed, can you suggest any reading material to get me upto speed with WMS, or anything else around this topic?
They do use MapNik under the hood!!

I'm not really sure what you are suggesting? designing my own  maps using cloudmade and then downloading all the tiles and storing on my own server?

Comment: You could try to design the tiled maps on cloudmade, and generate all tiles using tilestache-seed.py script (using the url provider of tilestache and the WMS address of your cloudmade map). Then, you can probably serve your tiles from your own server, but maybe this violate Cloudmade use rights and maybe Cloudmade block such usage. I could try if you provide me your Cloudmade WMS url

Comment: Cloudmade seems to allow caching as mentionnend on the website main page.

Answer (score 2):

you can use prepared styles or create your own in [cloudmade](http://maps.cloudmade.com/editor), this service offers 500K tiles free per month.

Comment: this option is no more available by cloudmade

Answer (score 1):

Once you have managed to store the OSM data in a local Postgis database, you are free to style your map as you want using Mapnik. Here is a list of available services with different styles:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/List_of_OSM_based_Services

For a start-off, you can also use [Maperitive](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive). You can style your map easily on the screen, and let the software create the tiles for openlayers: http://ksmapper.blogspot.de/2011/08/simple-openstreetmap-tile-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mapbox tiles. just create a layer and add it to map.

```
var mapbox = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(
                "MapBox",
                [
                    "http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/[mapid]/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
                    "http://b.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/[mapid]/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
                    "http://c.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/[mapid]/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
                    "http://d.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/[mapid]/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"
                ], {
                    attribution: "Tiles &copy; <a href='http://mapbox.com/'>MapBox</a>",
                    sphericalMercator: true,
                    wrapDateLine: false,
                    // numZoomLevels: 5,
                    isBaseLayer:true
                }
            );
            map.addLayer(mapbox);
```